# Some apps are upside down

Tags: ipad

I locked the orientation of my iPad upside down because I’m charging it and the cable would be in the way while using it.

I noticed one app* does not “respect” this and displays in the “classic” orientation. The moment I open it it shows like that including the system items like the date, time, Wi-Fi signal and battery percentage. Even the system swipes from down for the Home Screen , from up for notifications or upper right for control centre are all upside down. When I return to Home Screen everything returns as it was (as I set in control centre). Other apps work normally.

I noticed similar behaviour with Skype on my iPhone, not sure if related.

* it is a country specific app, not well known: https://apps.apple.com/si/app/zpstest-mipor/id1143544487

Comment: This is solely the fault of the app developer. You should contact them to see if they are 1/ aware of the problem and 2/ if they are going to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to the specific app not support orientations correctly. App developers are supposed to either support this feature OR alternatively mark their app as only supporting on of the available orientations.

In your case it seems the developer has not done their job properly. You'll need to file a bug report with the app developer and hope for an app update.